# how to convert from df to a time series in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

i have a data frame with a year column of type numeric and a avgtemp column of type numeric, so how can i convert it to a time series with a good format

Example:

```
 year AvgTempZScore
   <dbl>         <dbl>
 1  1835         0.109
 2  1836         0.168
 3  1837         0.177
 4  1838         0.143
 5  1839         0.188
 6  1840         0.198
 7  1841         0.200
 8  1842         0.230
 9  1843         0.237
10  1844         0.194
```

Str

```
tibble [179 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ year         : num [1:179] 1835 1836 1837 1838 1839 ...
 $ AvgTempZScore: num [1:179] 0.109 0.168 0.177 0.143 0.188 ...
```

Comment: What is a "good format"? What have you tried that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful using `ts()` function.

````
db=structure(list(year = c(1835,1836,1837,1838,1839,1840,1841,1842,1843,1844), 
               AvgTempZScore = c(0.109,0.168,0.177,0.143,0.188,0.198,0.200,0.230,0.237,0.194)), 
          row.names = c(1:10),
          class = "data.frame")
str(db)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ year         : num  1835 1836 1837 1838 1839 ...
# $ AvgTempZScore: num  0.109 0.168 0.177 0.143 0.188 0.198 0.2 0.23 0.237 0.194
db = ts(db,frequency = 1,start=1835, end=1844)
str(db)
#Time-Series [1:10, 1:2] from 1835 to 1844: 1835 1836 1837 1838 1839 ...
#- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#..$ : NULL
#..$ : chr [1:2] "year" "AvgTempZScore"#```
````

Answer (score 0):

With `xts`and `lubridate`:

```
xts::xts(x = df$AvgTempZScore,order.by = lubridate::ymd(df$year, truncated = 2L))
            [,1]
1835-01-01 0.109
1836-01-01 0.168
1837-01-01 0.177
1838-01-01 0.143
1839-01-01 0.188
1840-01-01 0.198
1841-01-01 0.200
1842-01-01 0.230
1843-01-01 0.237
1844-01-01 0.19
```